# try to subsitute intersect with Correlated sub query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to learn correlated sub query and try to substitute intersect set operator with it. But sub query returns nothing which confuse me. Can anyone tell the reason? Really appreciated.

```
select custid,empid
from sales.Orders
where orderdate>='20080101' and orderdate<('20080201')
intersect
select custid,empid
from sales.Orders
where orderdate>='20080201' and orderdate<('20080301');


select b.custid,b.empid
from sales.Orders as b
where exists
(select * from sales.Orders as a where a.orderid=b.orderid and a.orderdate>='20080101' and a.orderdate<'20080201')
and
exists
(select * from sales.Orders as c where c.orderid=b.orderid and c.orderdate>='20080201' and c.orderdate<'20080301')
order by b.custid
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use where orderdate='20080201'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correlating on `orderid` where you should be correlating on `custid` and `empid`.

```
select b.custid,
       b.empid
from sales.Orders as b
where exists (
             select * 
             from sales.Orders as a 
             where a.custid=b.custid and 
                   a.empid=b.empid and 
                   a.orderdate>='20080101' and 
                   a.orderdate<'20080201'
             ) and
      exists (
             select * 
             from sales.Orders as c 
             where c.custid=b.custid and 
                   c.empid=b.empid and 
                   c.orderdate>='20080201' and 
                   c.orderdate<'20080301'
             )
order by b.custid
```

This query will however not give you the exact same result since `intersect` removes duplicates from the result. That can be fixed by using `distinct` in the correlated version.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I understand what mistake I made.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` and `CASE` like this

```
SELECT custid,empid
FROM sales.Orders
WHERE (orderdate>='20080101' and orderdate<('20080201')) OR (orderdate>='20080201' and orderdate<('20080301'))
GROUP BY custid,empid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate>='20080101' and orderdate<('20080201') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate>='20080201' and orderdate<('20080301') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```